# How to Populate ListBox with Linq to Sql C#

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I have a question of how to populate a ListBox with data from Database without the columns of db and curly brackets 
here is my code:

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var history =( from a in db.ResultsHistories
            where
                a.PlayerOne == _playerOne && a.PlayerTwo == comboBox.Text ||
                a.PlayerTwo == _playerOne && a.PlayerOne == comboBox.Text
            select new
            {
                a.PlayerOne,
                a.PlayerTwo,
                a.Date,
                a.ResultOne,
                a.ResultTwo
            }).ToList();

        listBox.ItemsSource = history;
```

And the result: [image]
I want only Data in these columns.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please have a look at the answer here:
[Multicolumn ListBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911026/multicolumn-listbox-in-wpf)

You can also use a DataGrid for this purpose.
The XAML code for that would be:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NamesDataGrid"></DataGrid>
```

and a very simple code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly List<Name> _nameList = new List<Name>
    {
        new Name("Eric","Clapton"),
        new Name("Mark", "Knopfler")
    };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NamesDataGrid.ItemsSource = _nameList;
    }
}

internal class Name
{
    public Name(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Which will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IF you're trying to return a new object you have to tell it the properties as

```
select new {PlayerOne = a.PlayerOne
            //More Properties Here
           }
```

So based off your example might look something like

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var history =( from a in db.ResultsHistories
        where
            a.PlayerOne == _playerOne && a.PlayerTwo == comboBox.Text ||
            a.PlayerTwo == _playerOne && a.PlayerOne == comboBox.Text
        select new
        {
            PlayerOne = a.PlayerOne,
            PlayerTwo = a.PlayerTwo,
            Date = a.Date,
            ResultOne = a.ResultOne,
            ResultTwo = a.ResultTwo
        }).ToList();

    listBox.ItemsSource = history;
```

This will return a list of new objects with no type but the properties will be there

**EDIT:**
If you want all data from the table where **PlayerOne and PlayerTwo equal a textbox value** just do

```
var history = db.ResultsHistories.Where(x => x.PlayerTwo == comboBox.Text || x.PlayerOne == comboBox.Text).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried what u suggest but it doesn't work. 
I just want instead of getting the {}, = ,and columns name Only the data of the db table.

Comment: SO you want all data regardless ?

Comment: exactly, but only the Data like PlayerOne, PlayerTwo ,etc. without the curly brackets  and the = or columns name

Comment: It's display the Classname.TableName in db

Comment: in Run Time, the listBox Show 
QuizGame.ResultHistory ( the class.tablename) without any data

Answer (score 0):

**try to add this**

- ", " +  betwwen the statements

  a.PlayerOne+ ", " +a.PlayerTwo+ ", " + a.Date+ ", " + a.ResultOne+ ", " + a.ResultTwo

**it will work**

Answer (score 0):

```
            <ListBox x:Name="listBx_ShowPersons">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding firstName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=", "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                    
            </ListBox>
```

`listBx_ShowPersons.ItemsSource = from p in _dataContext.Persons select new { p.firstName, p.lastName };`