# string.Format - format two variables in two columns

Tags: c#, listbox, tostring, string.format

I am working on one app and i need help.
In this app, there is a listbox where will be showed all users (something like scoreboard). In method ToString() of users i have set string.Format to return two variables (Name and Money).
But when i run that application i get on output something like this:

```
bustercze   147
JohnyPrcina  158
anotherPlayer  47
```

But i want the output be like this:

```
bustercze       147
JohnyPrcina     158
anotherPlayer   47
```

I hope you got me right. And that you can help me.

My ToString() code:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}   {1}", Jmeno, Penize);
    }
```

What i already tried:
1. http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/ (didnt help)
2. [Format a string into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978311/format-a-string-into-columns) (also didnt help)

Comment: Are you using a WPF listbox? It is probably a font issue. But If WPF listbox, better to make a template with two columns, rather than padding.

Comment: This should be helpful - make an ItemTemplate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911026/multicolumn-listbox-in-wpf

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Winforms: You way may work only if you use a fixed font like Courier or Consolas. Other than that do use a ListView instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ToString() to do this. Use a template like this in your WPF listbox

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Scores}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="JmenoColumn"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="PenizeColumn"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Jmeno}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Penize}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Then you can get this:

[image]

**Old answer.** (addresses ToString() question)
Use PadRight, e.g.,

```
string.Format("{0}{1}", Jmeno.PadRight(20), Penize)
```

The code

```
int padding = 15;
string Jmeno = "bustercze";
int Penize = 147;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", Jmeno.PadRight(padding), Penize));
Jmeno = "JohnyPrcina";
Penize = 158;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", Jmeno.PadRight(padding), Penize));
Jmeno = "anotherPlayer";
Penize = 47;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", Jmeno.PadRight(padding), Penize));
```

produces

```
bustercze      147
JohnyPrcina    158
anotherPlayer  47
```

Comment: Xiaoy312 has a good answer too, though PadRight will let you specify the padding character... if that has any value. Plus you can modify the padding with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format : `"{0, -13} {1}"`

Note: You may want to change 13 to 20 or 25, depends on how long `Jmeno` can get.

---

EDIT: If you are display this in a listbox, you need to use a monospace font :

Add this line in below `InitializeComponent()`, or before/after populating the data :

```
listbox.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, listbox.Font.Size);
```

Comment: Am i doing something wrong ? :D 
My code:
public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0,-13} {1}", Jmeno, Penize);
        }
Output:
https://ctrlv.cz/KPWc

Comment: Are you display it on a listbox, checkbox, listview? This is due to not having a monospace font. ("1il" appears shorter than "MQ")

Comment: I am displaying it in ListBox
So how can i fix that ?

Comment: @LukasSeidler Updated my answer

Comment: I might look like a total stupid right now. But what i am getting is this:
"ListBox doesnt contain definition for Font"
And
"FontFamily doesnt contain a definition for GenericMonospace"

I dont know if it will help you somehow but i am using WPF no WinForm

Comment: I would recommend not using ToString to do this, but instead use the XAML to display Jmeno and Penize separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [advanced features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) of [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx):

```
string.Format("{0,-13}{1}")
```

You can do the same thing by writing `str.PadRight(10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can format string this way, the `-16` defines here the number of alignment space you want in the left side, if you want right side then you can use`+` an set it as based on highest possible length of `Jmeno`

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0,-16}{1}", Jmeno, Penize);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting correct take a look at here https://dotnetfiddle.net/XDkx5O and check your other things

Comment: then i think it might be what Xiaoy312 said:
This is due to not having a monospace font. ("1il" appears shorter than "MQ")

Can this be fixed somehow ? Maybe by changing font ?